# Array Definition in vba-excel

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I got in trouble in a part of my code. I have an variable that changes by the the number of filled rows.I have defined an array from 0 to that number but I receive "Constant Expression Required" Error. I would be thankful if anyone could help me.

```
 Sub test()
   Lastrow = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
   Dim f(0 To Lastrow) As Double
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't dim an array with variable, just constant

You need dim the array before, and redim it to your variable.
With redim:

```
Sub test()
   Dim f() As Double
   Lastrow = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
   Redim f(0 To Lastrow)
End Sub
```

With high constant (a bad way)

```
 Sub test()
       Dim f(35000) As Double
       Lastrow = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but I don't think you can dim using a variable. You might be able to redim..?

Comment: Would you please tell me how I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
sn=cells(1).currentregion
```

You don't need a 'last row' variable.